# Use a ternary operator to check for key in array exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm currently using a ternary operator to return true if `reportDate.parent` exists. The problem is that it returns true but for some arrays that return there are no `value` properties, so the report breaks.

```
{
        reportData.parent && (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Report/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

The below breaks:

```
parent: Array(3)
0: {dateTime: "05/09/2018"}
1: {dateTime: "16/06/2018"}
2: {dateTime: "19/03/2018"}
length: 3
```

The below works because it has at least 1 value:

```
parent: Array(3)
0: {dateTime: "05/09/2018", value: 2}
1: {dateTime: "16/06/2018"}
2: {dateTime: "19/03/2018"}
length: 3
```

I need to do the check at this top level before the report component is returned, something like:

```
{
    reportData.parent.value === undefined && (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Report />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Do I or can I use a ternary operator or another method of conditional rendering here?

To reiterate I want the report to return only if there is at least one value in the array.

Update: I am only looking to see if the key(named value) exists (not simply if a value exists inside the array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To reiterate I want the report to return only if there is at least one
>   value in the array.

You might try this:

```
{
    reportData.parent.length > 0 && (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Report />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

### Updated

Based on your comments, I come up with this solution

```js
let parent1 = [
  {
    dateTime: "05/09/2018",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    dateTime: "16/06/2018"
  },
  {
    dateTime: "19/03/2018"
  }
];
let parent2 = [
  {
    dateTime: "05/09/2018"
  },
  {
    dateTime: "16/06/2018"
  },
  {
    dateTime: "19/03/2018"
  }
];

var hasValue = function(element) {
  return element.hasOwnProperty('value')
};

console.log(parent1.some(hasValue)); // true
console.log(parent2.some(hasValue)); // false
```

And then...

```
{
    reportData.parent.length > 0 && reportData.parent.some(hasValue) && (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Report />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Hopefully, it works as expected

Comment: Yes this gives the length of array, all my arrays will have a length, I want to find return truthy if the array has a key called value inside

Comment: Got it! Well then, you have to iterate all over your array and use myObj.hasOwnProperty('key') to check an object's own keys, it will only return true if key is available on myObj directly

Comment: That sounds correct, the question is how can I add this to my ternary operator?

Comment: @TomRudge I've updated my answer, please give it a try and let me know if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the case `value` is always number you can use `some`

```
reportData.parent.some(a => !!a.value)
```

Comment: I thought this solution would be close but it complains .some is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for a truthy value

```
{
    reportData.parent.value && (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Report />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: .value is not a path but a key

Comment: Yes, it will test if `value` really exists, and return true or false accordingly

Comment: it returns false in both my example arrays because its looking for .value and that does not exist. Please refer to arrays in question